# sails.js / Waterline Many to many through association

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have been trying to add many to many through relation but it fails every time in run `save query`

I have raised issue here https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/issues/42.

Not copy pasting any of the code here, as github issue can be referenced.

Thanks for any help